# Which Panel to use in Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, jpanel

I would like to have a JTable component in one panel to take up as much space as the window allows. Underneath, however, I would like to add another, fixed size panel with a few buttons in it. WHich layout to use to allow the bottom panel be of fixed size, while allowing JTable panel to stretch according to size of the window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to visualize what you want exactly, but here's an excerpt from Oracle that may help you:

**Scenario:** You need to display a component in as much space as it can get.

> If it is the only component in its container, use GridLayout or BorderLayout. Otherwise, BorderLayout or GridBagLayout might be a good
>   match.
>
> If you use BorderLayout, you will need to put the space-hungry
>   component in the center. With GridBagLayout, you will need to set the
>   constraints for the component so that fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH.
>   Another possibility is to use BoxLayout, making the space-hungry
>   component specify very large preferred and maximum sizes.

**Scenario:** You need to display a few components in a compact row at their natural size.

> Consider using a JPanel to group the components and using either the JPanel's default FlowLayout manager or the BoxLayout manager.
>   SpringLayout is also good for this.

**Scenario:** You need to display a few components of the same size in rows and columns.

> GridLayout is perfect for this.

**Scenario:** You need to display a few components in a row or column, possibly with varying amounts of space between them, custom alignment, or custom component sizes.

> BoxLayout is perfect for this.

**Scenario:** You need to display aligned columns, as in a form-like interface where a column of labels is used to describe text fields in an adjacent column.

> SpringLayout is a natural choice for this. The SpringUtilities class used by several Tutorial examples defines a makeCompactGrid
>   method that lets you easily align multiple rows and columns of
>   components.

**Scenario:** You have a complex layout with many components.

> Consider either using a very flexible layout manager such as
>   GridBagLayout or SpringLayout, or grouping the components into one or
>   more JPanels to simplify layout. If you take the latter approach, each
>   JPanel might use a different layout manager.

**Source:** [Oracle: Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to achieve it is to use `BorderLayout`. Put your table in the center. Then create yet another panel with `FlowLayout` and put it to the south of your main panel.

Comment: That aligned the table on top of the button, but if I want to resize the window, the table stops resizing at some point, but takes up fixed potion of the window. It is wrapped in Scroll pane btw

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Was using North instead of Center. Why does it make a difference? in both cases I am telling the table to fill the viewPort...